# how to use update with join condition on 3 tables in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
UPDATE patient 
SET p.patient_name='Keerthi',
c.pat_cnt_pincode=560765
FROM patient as p 
        left JOIN patient_contact AS c on c.pat_cnt_email_id=p.patient_email 
        WHERE   p.patient_id=921;
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Your title says 3 tables, but the query only references two.  And, in Postgres, you can only update one table.

Answer (score 0):

You can only update one table in a single statement.  But, you could do:

```
with p as (
      update patient p
          set patient_name = 'Keerthi'
          where p.patient_id = 921
      returning *
     )
update patient_contact pc
    set pat_cnt_pincode = 560765
    from p
    where pc.pat_cnt_email_id = p.patient_email;
```

Comment: ERROR:  column "patient_name" of relation "lt_transmas_patient" does not exist
LINE 3:           set patient_name = 'Keerthi'
                      ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "patient_name" of relation "lt_transmas_patient" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 62

Comment: @Rekha . . . This is using the column and table references in your query.  I don't know what your tables really are, but there is no `lt_transmas_patient` in the question.  (There was a typo in the answer but it was not related to that column.

Comment: UPDATE lt_transmas_patient 
SET p.patient_name='Keerthi',
c.pat_cnt_pincode=560765,
a.apnt_reason_visit='Visit Notes Added'
FROM lt_transmas_patient as p 
  left JOIN lt_transmas_patient_contact AS c on c.pat_cnt_email_id=p.patient_email 
  left JOIN ams.ams_transmap_appointment a on a.apnt_patient_id=p.patient_id
  WHERE   p.patient_id=921;

Comment: @Rekha . . . That query has nothing to do with my answer.

Comment: tht r the 3 tables which iam using how can i update columns in those tables by using joins pls